# Inserting a PowerShell command into c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to use this PowerShell command in a C# project:

```
Get-VM -Name Win8-Henry | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Select MacAddress
```

This is what I normally do in c#:

```
public static void MacAdd(string machineName,Runspace run) {
    // Get-VM -Name Win8-Henry | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Select MacAddress
    Command command = new Command("Get-VM");
    command.Parameters.Add("Name", machineName);

    using (Pipeline hostPipeline = run.CreatePipeline())
    {
        hostPipeline.Commands.Add(command);
        Collection<PSObject> echos = hostPipeline.Invoke();
        hostPipeline.Stop();
    }
}
```

What I need help with is adding the second command, and then using the pipeline.

Comment: hostPipeline.Commands.Add(anotherCommand) and then Invoke() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`AddScript()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the [`PowerShell` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
var Command = String.Format("Get-VM -Name {0} | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Select MacAddress", computername);
var PowerShell = PowerShell.Create();
PowerShell.AddScript(Command);
PowerShell.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the other commands to the pipeline too :)

```
hostPipeline.Commands.Add(new Command("Get-VMNetworkAdapter"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to share what I do when I have a script that I need to execute in an application.  I can then replace the parameters (i.e., "$!$machineName$!$" easily and get the result cleanly.

```
Dim lxScript As XElement = <Script>
.{
Get-VM -Name $!$machineName$!$ | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Select MacAddress
}                         
                     </Script>
```